# How do I create a testcase that targets a specified branch?

Tags: llvm, klee, symbolic-execution

I try to "dynamic symbolic execution" with klee.

How do I create a testcase that targets a specified branch?

```
int a = 0;
klee_make_symbolic(&a, sizeof(a), "a");
if (a == 0) 
    ... // I want to touch only this branch
else if (a > 0)
    ...
else
    ...
```

Is there any option to make specified branch?

I don't want to make all testcases.

Answer (score 0):

instrument an `assert(0);` statement into the branch you interested and then run klee with the parameter `-exit-on-error-type=Assert`.

KLEE will exit and genrate a test case for the path you instrumented. This is the easiest way I come up with.